# I am not able expose a service in kubernetes cluster to the internet

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubectl, kubernetes-pod, azure-aks

I have created a simple hello world service in my kubernetes cluster. I am not using any cloud provider and have created it in a simple Ubuntu 16.04 server from scratch.
I am able to access the service inside the cluster but now when I want to expose it to the internet, it does not work.

Here is the yml file - deployment.yml

[image]

And this is the result of the command - kubectl get all:

[image]

Now when I am trying to access the external IP with the port in my browser, i.e., **172.31.8.110:8080**, it does not work.

**NOTE:** I also tried the NodePort Service Type, but then it does not provide any external IP to me. The state remains pending under the "External IP" tab when I do "kubectl get services".

How to resolve this??

Comment: If you try NodePort Service Type, test should be [node_ip]:[nodeport] where node_ip is obtained from kubectl get nodes -o wide and nodeport=30001. And also allow firewall: gcloud compute firewall-rules create test-node-port --allow tcp:30001

Comment: You can also see an example [here](https://github.com/DanyLan/GKE-EXPOSE-SERVICES/blob/master/NodePort.md)

Comment: Do you use the AKS or just configure the Kubernetes cluster yourself in the Azure VM?

Comment: As first, please check SO FAQ [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You should avoid posting pics, you always should use `codeSample` and posting configs/errors as text. Another thing, you have 2 cloud providers tag: Azure Cloud (AKS) and Google Cloud Platform (GKE). Which one you are using? Exposing service depends on your env and your config. Please provide more focused details about your env and config, what you are using and how you want to expose id (MetalLB, Ingress, LoadBalancer, NodePort, etc).

Comment: I have used the NodePort Service Type as well and the result of kubectl get all also displays everything correclty but when I try to access the service in my browser by <Public IP of node>:30001, it does not connect. I also tried with the <master node public IP>:30001 but still it does not work.

Comment: I am not using any cloud provider, I have setup the cluster from the scratch, and all protocols are in place. Also, I am able to curl locally and have a positive response, the issue is just when I try to access the service through the internet.

Comment: Where do you set up the cluster? Local machines?

Comment: I have set up the cluster in a Ubuntu 16.04 LTS machine

Comment: I mean it's local machine or the Azure VM?

Comment: It's the AWS Ubuntu 16.04 instance

Answer (score 1):

I believe you might have a mix of networking problems tied together. 
First of all, `172.31.8.110` belongs to a [private network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network), and it is not routable via Internet. So make sure that the location you are trying to browse from can reach the destination (i.e. same private network).

As a quick test you can make an ssh connection to your master node and then check if you can open the page:
`curl 172.31.8.110:8080`

In order to expose it to Internet, you need a to use a public IP for your master node, not internal one. Then update your Service `externalIPs` accordingly.

Also make sure that your firewall allows network connections from public Internet to `8080` on master node.

In any case I suggest that you use this configuration for testing purposes only, as it is generally bad idea to use master node for service exposure, because this applies extra networking load on the master and widens security surface. Use something like an Ingress controller (like [Nginx](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx) or other) + [Ingress resource](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/) instead.

Comment: I used the public IP itself, when I try to access within the cluster I am able to access the service, the only issue comes when I am trying to access through the nternet. I have checked the ports as well and nothing is blocked.

Comment: This is what I mean, you cannot access 172.16.0.0/12 IP range from the Internet, your server must have an IP which does not belong to a private network range.

Comment: but this IP (172.31.8.110)got assigned as public IP of my kuberenetes master machine  as soon as the serevr got re - started. Am I missing anyting here?

Comment: I think we should restart the question :) what are you trying to accomplish? 
Do you want to expose the service only in your internal 172.x.x network only or you want the service to be accessible from public Internet?

Can you ssh to server from your notebook via 172.31.8.110?

Comment: I want to expsoe my service to the outside world. Yes I was able to ssh.

Answer (score 0):

One option is also to do SSH local port forwarding.

```
ssh -L <local-port><private-ip-on-your-server><remote-port> <ip-of-your-server>
```

So in your case for example:

```
ssh -L 8888:172.31.8.110:8080 <ip-of-your-ubuntu-server>
```

Then you can simply go to your browser and configure a SOCKS Proxy for localhost:8888.

Then you can access the site on http://localhost:8888 .